# Should frameless glass shower door hinges be screwed into the wall at an angle?

Tags: doors, shower, hinges, glass

I recently had shower glass & door installed - but the shower door hinges have their screws (ones that go into the tile wall) are screwed in at an angle, so they do not sit flush against the hinge.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

All the screws are this way except the center one, I am wondering if this is normal?

I asked the guy who installed it, he said it is purposefully done that way so that it would be able to withstand the weight of the glass door.

Some details of the project:

- This is a torn down to the studs kind of project
- There are double studs behind the tile where the hinges are
- The door is a 90 degree door

Any of you know if this is normal?

Comment: Ask the installer to show you the documentation that says that angled is the proper way to install them. Better yet get the install PDF first so you can call his bluff.

Comment: I would say that it's a perfectly normal thing to do when one has pre-drilled pilot holes in ceramic tiles, yet has gotten their location _just_ off. This saves the effort of pulling the tiles off the wall, retilling and redrilling. It is _not_ however, something that should be done by a professional installer who values his reputation.

Comment: You added more info.  Is there more you want to ask other then is it normal?

Comment: It is disappointing to have the screws off angle, but probably it will not affect the operation of the door over its lifetime. The screws will probably not loosen with use. I would use it and see what happens. Do you know where the doubled studs are in relation to these screws? Did the glass installer know there were double studs there? What is the hortrizontal distance between the screws?

Comment: Are there only three screws for each hinge? One in the center and two inside? What are the recommendations/requirements for framing for this door?

Comment: @JimStewart The frame/double studs' location are right behind the tile (and wall), so it is not an issue with screw location. The glass installer knew about this too.

Comment: @JimStewart There are only 3 screws per hinge and I am not sure what is the recommendation/requirements for the door. I did ask for documentation to support the angled screws etc, but the installer said there is none. I looked up a similar type of hinge manual on the internet and nothing seems to indicate angled screws or anything like that. O yes - the door is functional - nothing wrong there. But just looks weird for a pro installation.

Comment: So is the lateral horizontal distance between the screw holes less than 1 inch?  Possibly, the holes are designed so that they could fit either into a single 2x stud (1.5" across) or into doubled studs. With the right tools and skill I think it would be possible to remove the angled screws one at a time, insert a dowel to fill the angled holes, then drill holes perpendicular to the wall. But this could go wrong and I advise you to try to accept this poor workmanship unless you find the screws loosening over time.

Comment: @JimStewart Thank you very much for your explanation and opinion - truly appreciated. Do you know what is the grey thing around one of the screw (you can see it in the bottom right picture above)? Is that like silicone or cement or grout?

Comment: Possibly the installation instructions specify a sealant in the hole and that is the grey substance around the screw.  I wonder if there is a pad between the bracket and the tile?

Comment: This argument applies to nails, not screws  especially into tiles or glass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any of you know if this is normal?

I would say **not normal**.

Looking closely at the photos i would say that if the manufacturer had wanted the screws to be at an angle then they would have set the countersinks in the brackets at that specified angle so the heads did not stick out proud of the bracket, They did not. The countersinks are straight so therefore one can assume that the screws SHOULD go in straight.

I would surmise that  the installer is feeding you a line to cover his mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Any screw installed at an angle will not be able to handle the sheer load vertically of the weight of the shower.   Once it loosens and it will it will pull at a much greater rate too.   Just no way.

Answer (score 0):

If this was a retrofit, and the bathroom hasn't been torn down to the studs, my guess is that this is just how things worked out.

Probably the location where the door needed to be installed aesthetically or to make the shower leak-proof was ever so slightly NEXT TO the stud. It looks like there is one screw more towards the center of the hinge, which looks like it goes in straight. The other ones probably had to be angled slightly in order to hit the stud, or they would have just gone into drywall and wouldn't be doing anything at all really (other than probably pull your tile off the wall).

If you were fully redoing the bathroom, including removing drywall, there would have been an opportunity to place more solid blocking where the hinges needed to go, but if that wasn't the case, the next base thing would be doing this, over having the screws not hold the door up at all.

You haven't given us many details about this project, so this is just a guess of course.

Comment: I apologize - I added more details of the project.

Answer (score 0):

This is ABSOLUTELY not normal, and a complete line of BS. I have been doing this for 14 years. There is no reason for that to be crooked. He drilled his pilot hole off center, and that is the only way he could get the screw to run. It actually weakens your hinge because the force is on the spine of the screw instead of the head. Also, he stripped out the other screw head probably because he was using an old tip on his impact. Sometimes the screws that come with the hinges can be poor quality, but this looks like a CRL GEN5370RB, and those install instructions say the screw should be installed flush into the countersunk back plate holes.

Answer (score 0):

Installed hundreds of glass shower enclosures. Yes in a perfect world the screws would sit evenly flush but if you've done them for a lot of years you would know to slightly angle your hole so as when you're screwing it in with your screw gun the chuck does not rub up against the hinge and mark it up. I work with a lot of other shower eclosure installers and this seems pretty common in the trade. This looks like it might be slightly more of an angle than I would do. Most important thing to do is to make sure you hit proper Wood backing with that there would be no issues with the door.
What would be more important would be if your installer did not pre shim inside the hinge to compensate for the door potentially sagging when the gaskets expand and contract